# Which disk is FreeNAS booting from?

Tags: boot, truenas

I've just installed FreeNAS to what I believe to be the USB stick. Is there anyway to tell for sure without rebooting the machine and removing the USB stick?

Answer (score 0):

Do a `ls -la` on the USB device and see if the OS files are there and if log files are being written to and created.

To help narrow down the /dev's use `udevinfo -q all -n /dev/sda`, where `/dev/sda` is the path to your disk.